# governor.queue() function leads to panic: arithmetic overflow 0x11 error. But why?

Tags: foundry, dao

I am currently testing multiple contracts, which contain everything that belongs to ERC20Votes Token and the Governor contract. I used the OpenZeppelin Wizard to set up the Dao. I haven't changed anything in the contracts, but now I try to test it on a forked main net. I can create a proposal, delegate tokens and vote, but once I try to governor.queue, it gives me the panic code 0x11, which is associated with an overflow or underflow.

Does anybody have a clue what could be the reason for that?

[image: Traces]